# A bounded recursive prime sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers

The last problem in the 2001 Polish Olympiad Round 3 Day 1 is proving a recursive prime sequence is bounded.

> The prime sequence $p_1, p_2, p_3, ...$ is defined as follows. $p_1$ and $p_2$ are primes. $p_n$ is the greatest prime divisor of $p_{n-1} + p_{n-2} + 2000$. Show that the sequence is bounded.

It is natural to ask if $2000$ can be generalized to an arbitrary positive integer $m$. The prevailed solution can be applied to any case if $m$ is even.

Here is a sketch. We pick a $k \in \mathbb{N}_+$ such that $\max \{ p_1,p_2 \} = k \cdot (m+3)! + 1$. Claim that this is a uniform bound for all $n$ and prove it by induction. Note that since $m$ is even, if $p_{n},p_{n+1} > 2$, then $p_{n-1} + p_{n-2} + m$ is also even. Hence the next term is at most half of it. And if one of $p_{n},p_{n+1}$ equals to $2$, the bound will be quite loose. In both cases, we can deduce that $p_n < k \cdot (m+3)! + m + 3$. And it is a cliché that $k \cdot (m+3)! + i$ is composite for $i = 2, \ldots m + 3$. Now the proof is completed.

But when it turns to the case of odd $m$, things get thoroughly different since now the even $p_{n-1} + p_{n-2} + m$ appears together with $p_{i} = 2$, and the burden of the other case flourishes. We cannot prove the bound in the same manner. So my questions are:

1. I verified a few cases in Mathematica that the odd case should be true. I would be quite apologetic if the conclusion is wrong. Is there a similar approach (other approaches are also welcomed) to prove the odd case?
2. During the enumeration for verifying, I notice that the upper bound is way too bad. Is there any better bound given $p_1$, $p_2$ and $m$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that the sequence $p_i$ is bounded](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1116498/prove-that-the-sequence-p-i-is-bounded) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24p_%7Bn-1%7D%2Bp_%7Bn-2%7D%2B2000%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aprime%20divisor&p=1). Note this other problem uses $2014$ instead of $2000$, but the basic proof approach, especially in the accepted answer, is the same.

Comment: FYI, note the search also found the AoPS threads [$p_{n+2}$ is the largest prime divisor of $p_n+p_{n+1}+2018$](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2260421p17491422) and [Sequence contains finitely many primes](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1624435p10179323) where $2018$ is used instead of $2000$, plus [A sequence of prime numbers](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h465372p2606610) where a general positive integer $m$ is used.

Comment: @JohnOmielan that last link asks about general $m$ but does not seem to give a solution where $m$ is coprime to $6$

Comment: I noticed you already solved the specific Olympiad problem, as well as the more general case where $m$ is even, but was asking about other issues, so I retracted my duplicate close vote. Nonetheless, I'm leaving my comments about the basically duplicate Math SE question and AoPS threads since you, plus any other readers, may find them useful.